# How to render some of triangles boundaries in a mesh

Tags: 3d, shader, line, render, mesh

I need to outline edges in geometry i render. Edges are defined as adjacent triangles boundaries if mesh bends on the border between them for certain degree. I compute these edges and store them in separate model for every mesh.

I wonder, how can i attain the result similar to one 3ds max can render?

[image]

This is how it looks if i just render both mesh and its edges model in case i have several layers of boxes piled on each other:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the angle between adjacent triangles normals and if the angle is beyond a certain threshold promote the edge as sharp.

To display wires over the polygons, you need to use polygon offset: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm